# i have weird syntaxe error in ocaml code

Tags: string, filter, ocaml, match

i just begin to use Caml and i'm trying to parse a git file: so i used match to filter the lines that begin with diff/@@ and here's what i tried to do:
 | ["diff"; _; before; after] -> out before;
            out after;

```
                 (match  Str.split (Str.regexp "/") file  with 
                     | String.concat "/" [_; path ; dest;file_c ]-> out path; 
                      out dest;
                      out file_c;
                     | _ -> ()
        )
```

i have a syntxe error here and here :
 | ["@@"; lines_deleted; lines_added; _] -> out lines_deleted;
                        out lines_added;

```
                   let   nb_lines_deleted = String.sub lines_deleted 2 ((String.length lines_deleted)-1) in
                     let  nb_lines_added = String.sub lines_added 2 ((String.length lines_added)-1) in
        ( match ( Str.split (Str.regexp ",") lines_deleted ) with 
                    | [_;  nb_lines_deleted;_; nb_lines_added] -> out nb_lines_deleted;
               out nb_lines_added;
                    | _ -> ()
                  )
           | _ -> ()
```

and i don't understand why! i tried diffrent things but nothing worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to use `match  with` for comparisons. For that you you must use `if then else`.

Comment: One can also use `match` in the following way: `match a = b with true -> ... | false -> ...`

Comment: @lukstafi you should be hung by the feet for suggesting to do this

Answer (score 3):

As Thomash says, the different alternatives of a `match` expression are built up from constants and data constructors (and names representing "wild cards" in essence). But you're trying to use a general expression there.

The following is analogous to what you're trying to do:

```
match x with
| a * b + 7 -> "case 1" (* Not a valid OCaml match *)
| _ -> "case 2"
```

The way a match really works is:

```
match x with
| 1 -> "case 1"
| 2 -> "case 2"
| _ -> "case N"
```

You need to use an `if` instead of a `match`:

```
if x = a * b + 7 then "case 1" else "case 2"
```

**Update:**

Here's how a match looks, roughly speaking:

```
match <<any expression>> with
| <<pattern>> -> <<expression>>
| <<pattern>> -> <<expression>
```

So you can have any expression between `match` and `with`. It's reasonable to have `Str.split` there. Patterns, on the other hand, are restricted. In essence they are like complicated *constant* values. They can also contain "wild-card" names that are defined by the match, i.e., they get set to the part of the value that matches at that point. But you could never have `Str.split` or `String.concat` in a pattern. For basic knowledge like this, it would be best to read a book or tutorial about OCaml.

Comment: than you :) you're suggesting that i'll  use an if instad of a match but can i use an (str.split ...) with an if too ?

Comment: You can use any boolean expression with an if. I don't think this is a useful question, though. I'll add some more text to my answer.